# How sort results with Google Drive SDK?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using the following methods to query entries from Google Drive. In my Android App I don't fetch all entries of a directory at once. With lazy loading I fetch the entries while the user scrolls thru the lists.

The problem is that the entries do come unsorted. I do sort them on my side but with lazy loading things become nasty. I can only sort what I have so the list has to be resorted with every new page that gets loaded.

How can I change that?

```
    FileList files = drive
            .files()
            .list()
            .setMaxResults(GdataConstants.REQUEST_ENTRIESPERPAGE)
            .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
            .setQ(buildFilesQuery(folderId, mimeTypes))
            .execute();
```

Comment: i dont think it is possible to get it sorted while fetching. I just looked thru the sdk myself. The reason i think why it is unsorted is because it can be sorted in any way, name/date/size, etc etc, which is ok if it is left to be done on the client side(your app side)

Comment: It's only ok on client side if you do have a handful of objects. Consider directories with thousands of pictures. You won't load everything at once and sort it on your device. The API needs to fetch on a page base, the device needs to do network traffic, thumbnails need to be fetched. There's a 100% chance that you do lazy loading lists in that case. If the user scrolls you fetch the next bulk of objects. But with unsorted results you need to re-sort after every request and the list-order changes. It's a pain for the user.

Answer (score 5):

The previous doclist API allowed sorting.
Its a missing feature that is impossible to implement client-side unless you only have a few unpaged results. Its impossible to implement for example a drive search and have the resulting files come sorted by name. I would have to preload the entire result set (possibly thousands) just to be able to sort them correctly.

See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/reference#Parameters where it says 'orderby'